# Remove LocalNotification Badge Number from launcher icon

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am trying to add a feature in app in which whenever i made a note, it will Call a `UILocalNotification` after few days (Hardcoded). Now, on `launcher Icons` i can see a red badge with marker "1". How can I remove this badge?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;`

Add that line in whatever code handles the user's interaction with the local notification. If you want the badge to be cleared when the local notification fires, you can't (because setting the notification's `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property to `0` would simply mean "don't change the existing badge.")

Comment: As per Apple documentation "Set to 0 (zero) to hide the badge number. The default is 0.". Refer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Jim That's for `UIApplication`. `UILocalNotification` behaves differently.

Comment: I am agree with you. I missed the context here.